# FileReader Image to Base64 Corrupted Conversion

Tags: javascript, base64, filereader

I am trying to convert an image from my local files to Base64 by JavaSctipt. 
For example please look at [this](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image) website.

When I browse a picture on the input beneath **Local File*** heading (input having id #form-base64-converter-encode-image-file) and then run this code in the console of the browser -

```
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new window.FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
    alert(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     alert('Error: ', error);
   };
}

var file = window.document.querySelector('#form-base64-converter-encode-image-file').files[0];
getBase64(file);
```

The script gives me a long string which is supposed to be the Base64 encoded image. But when I assign the string in the source of an image the image won't show up. The string is corrupted or not properly Base64 encoded. What do I need to do for a proper Base64 string which I can then assign in **src** attribute of an `<image>` tag?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/13330165) answer your query?

Comment: no sorry it doesn't.